# Are there any disadvantages to using openat() for path resolution?

Tags: c

The man page for `openat(2)` describes a lot of its advantages compared to `open(2)`, but it doesn't seem to include any sort of disadvantages.

Concatenating paths in C manually can be a pain (assuming one doesn't want to / can't offload most of the allocation logic to `asprintf(3)`, which is unfortunately not part of POSIX), so I was considering, instead, acquiring a file descriptor for a base directory and using that to access files relatively to the directory with `openat(2)`.

Are there any disadvantages to this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one disadvantage: using `openat` in this way requires an extra file descriptor.

As far as I’m aware, that’s the only one (and a minor one at that, in my opinion).

Comment: How about using `chdir()`?

Comment: @user16217248 that’s much more invasive, it affects all relative file operations and is inherited by `fork()`. `chdir()` also exposes you to races, if you want to use that instead of `openat()` you should use `fchdir()` instead.